# 403 Error on AJAX Request in add new item (collection field)

Tags: ajax, entities

I have normal content type which has 12 collection fields 
each field has unlimited value
when i try to click `add new item` on any field it gives me ajax error

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 403
Debugging information follows.
Path: /?q=system/ajax
StatusText: Forbidden
ResponseText:
```

I have another content type and also has collection field with unlimited value .. but it works without any problem
so please help me why some content type has error and the other doesn't have

by the way: i use D7 and i upgraded it to 7.35 but this problem was before the upgrading

i have checked all the answers in the `Drupal Answers` but unfortunately did it help

**edit:**

```
ResponseText:
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.base.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.base-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.menus.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.menus-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.messages.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.messages-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.theme.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/system/system.theme-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.1.7.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/date/date_repeat_field/date_repeat_field.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/field/theme/field.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/field/theme/field-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/field_hidden/field_hidden.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/node/node.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/recieve_orders/css/orders_styles.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/search/search.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/search/search-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/user/user.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/user/user-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/views/css/views-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.uid1.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/modules/adminimal_admin_menu/adminimal_admin_menu.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/modules/shortcut/shortcut-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/themes/adminimal_theme/css/reset.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/themes/adminimal_theme/css/style.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/themes/adminimal_theme/css/style-rtl.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/themes/adminimal_theme/css/mobile.css?nlmla7");
@import url("http://example.org/sites/all/themes/adminimal_theme/css/tablet.css?nlmla7");ySite.org/sites/all/themes/adminimal_theme/css/tablet.css?nlmla7");
```

and there are too many custom modules in my site

**but** the thing which make me more conflicted is why it doesn't give error in the other content type

Comment: Is there any custom modules your installation? What's the response text content?

Comment: @tunic I added the response text but i have very much costume modules

Comment: Hard to know, the error is pretty strange. I suggest to disable your custom modules or use a XDebug to debug the error.

Comment: do you thing it can be related to the **memory limit** in the php.ini because i have too much collection fields with unlimited value in the same form ,, if can be i will call my hosting company to increase it because it is not possible from my side

Comment: and if some module has problem ,, this problem must affect on the any other content type ... i am just thinking logically ;)

Comment: Memory limit errors can be seen in the PHP error log (although I don't think this error comes from that). Ask your hosting provider to know how you can check the error log. If you haven't check the error log you should.

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth we just wrestled with this for a while on our own sites. The solution actually ended up being disabling cloudflare on 'system/ajax' URLs. If you're running CF and have this problem - try it!